# Trouble reading a messy CSV file in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have been trying to read a CSV into R. The CSV is separated in a strange way with all values within one column separated by commas like in this picture[image: this picture]. The top row is the column names and then below are the values
When I try `read_csv("filename")` nothing shows up in the tibble except a bunch of NA values like in this picture after running the view function [image]. How can I approach this?

Here is the data for reference

```
, Calories, Fat (g), Carb. (g), Fiber (g), Protein (g)
Chonga Bagel,300,5,50,3,12
8-Grain Roll,380,6,70,7,10
Almond Croissant,410,22,45,3,10
Apple Fritter,460,23,56,2,7
Banana Nut Bread,420,22,52,2,6
Blueberry Muffin with Yogurt and Honey,380,16,53,1,6
Blueberry Scone,420,17,61,2,5
Butter Croissant,240,12,28,1,5
Butterfly Cookie,350,22,38,0,2
Cheese Danish,320,16,36,1,8
Chewy Chocolate Cookie,170,5,30,2,2
Chocolate Chip Cookie,310,15,42,2,4
Chocolate Chunk Muffin,440,21,60,2,7
Chocolate Croissant,330,18,38,1,6
Chocolate Hazelnut Croissant,390,22,43,2,7
Chocolate Marble Loaf Cake,490,24,64,2,6
Cinnamon Morning Bun,390,15,56,2,8
Cinnamon Raisin Bagel,270,1,58,3,9
Classic Coffee Cake,390,16,57,1,5
Cookie Butter Bar,360,23,36,0,2
```

Comment: Can you paste the first few lines of the raw CSV file into your question so we can see what the raw data looks like? My guess is that comma isn't a "normal" comma. Where did the CSV file come from?

Comment: I got the file from here - https://www.kaggle.com/starbucks/starbucks-menu/kernels. The file is called starbucks-menu-nutrition-food.csv.

Comment: Please put the data in the question. It should not be necessary to register for an account at an external website to see the data to help you.

Comment: Consider to use `read.table` with `separator = ','`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code to read the data

```
df = read.csv("starbucks-menu-nutrition-food.csv", skipNul = T)

head(df, 2)

        ÿþ Calories Fat..g. Carb...g. Fiber..g. Protein..g.
1 Chonga Bagel      300       5        50         3          12
2 8-Grain Roll      380       6        70         7          10
```

Then you may consider renaming the columns like for e.g.

```
colnames(df) <- c("Food", "Calories", "Fat", "Carb", "Fiber", "Protein")
```

for further processing of the data.